# Nautilus keyboard shortcut for expanding/collapsing folders

Tags: ubuntu, nautilus

In Nautilus' **list view**, is there a keyboard shortcut for expanding or collapsing a folder? I reckon this is just `left` and `right` arrow keys for MacOSX (Finder)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`+` and `-` work here.